# zentyal on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: apache2, dpkg, derivatives

I tried installing Zentyal on my ubuntu 13.10-serve using the ppa-method (as I don't want to reinstall the OS).

At first, I added `deb http://archive.zentyal.org/zentyal 3.3 main extra` to my `sources.list` and ran `sudo apt-get update`, followed by a `sudo apt-get install zentyal`.

Stripped by the installation of the dependencies, you can find the installation log here (unfortunately in German): http://pastebin.com/vLN2UWgn . The output at the end of the log is just the output from `etckeeper`.

As stated in the log, the post-install script of `zentyal-core` failed. Thus, I tried running `zentyal-core.postinst` in `/var/lib/dpkg/info`. There is some strange behaviour to be observed now.

`sudo ./zentyal-core.postinst` gives:

`Use of uninitialized value $action in string eq at /usr/share/debconf/frontend line 27.`

whereas `sudo bash zentyal-core.postinst` gives:

```
 Can't exec "zentyal-core.config": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl/5.14/IPC/Open3.pm line 186.
 open2: exec of zentyal-core.config configure  failed at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/ConfModule.pm line 59
```

In case that it matters, my default shell is `fish` (but not for `root`, that one is using `bash`).

After removing the post-install script, dpkg runs fine, but pointing firefox at my server just shows the default apache welcome page ("This is the default webpage ... blah blah").

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Zentyal ISO instead of PPA. It worked for me. Can be downloaded here (3.4):
http://www.zentyal.org/server/